# How can I write a CPAN module to support multiple Perl versions?

Tags: perl, cpan

Let's say I have a module on CPAN and I'd like to upgrade it to use features from newer Perls.  Right now, as I understand it, if I do that I'm putting a line in the sand saying from this version on you can only use my module if you have version X of Perl.

Is there a clean/canonical way to support two different branches of the same module on CPAN?

i.e., the 2.x series would continue to be maintained for versions back to 5.8.x, while 3.x would be for version 5.16+.

Comment: I don't think I was clear enough - I'm trying to get CPAN to consider multiple versions of the same module to be supported, just like Perl 5.18.4 and 5.20.2 are both considered supported versions of Perl 5 (right now).

That way I can remove all 5.8isms from the active code base while still supporting 5.8 on a less active code base (without changing the module name)

Comment: You'll have to explain a little better. The `cpan` utility will only install the latest version of any module. If you want an earlier one then you have to manually download, build, test and install it. You could write a wrapper module that loads different worker modules depending on the interpreter version, but they would have to have different names.

Comment: I *think* cpxxxan solves the problem I'm interested in, although I don't know if there's a way to make it more contract based.

It's something I'm a bit nervous to google at work ...

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The problem with having two branches with the same name is that `cpan The::Module` will needlessly fail for some users (since it will always get the latest version). They would still be able to install the older version of the module, but it would be far more cumbersome. Instead, change the module to

```
package The::Module;
do($] < 5.016 ? 'The/Module/Pre5016.pm' : 'The/Module/5016.pm')
   or die $@ || $!;
1;
```

If only limited parts of the module are different, you could simply use

```
sub _foo_compatible { ... }

sub _foo_fast { ... }

*foo = $] < 5.016 ? \&_foo_compatible : \&_foo_fast;
```

This second method has the disadvantage of needing both subs to compile in 5.8 (unless you add `eval EXPR` to the mix).

Comment: That's still one version of the module, it just does different things based on the version; what I'm wondering is if I can publish Module v2.x to CPAN and have perl 5.8.9 use that, while publishing Module v3.x is used by anything newer.

The trick is, how can I get CPAN / cpanm / whatever to maintain the distinction by module version, rather than having my module handle it all?

Comment: While this may work, it's wrong to advocate the use of deprecated variables. `$^V` has been documented as being *Deprecated in Perl 5.6* ever since perlvar v5.14.0

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/76377/discussion-between-borodin-and-ikegami).

Comment: @Borodin, It was a documentation bug. `$]` was never deprecated, and is [no longer](http://perl5.git.perl.org/perl.git/commitdiff/4ad0ecd4c5a81ed8f71804b908656dca23f4867e) marked as deprecated.

Comment: Wouldn't `require` remove the need for the `or die ...` clutter?

Comment: @Slade, `require` should only be used with files that specify a `package`.So there are two options. Either have the files use `package The::Module`, or use `do`.

Answer (score 5):

The `$]` variable has been deprecated in favour of [the `$^V` variable](http://perldoc.perl.org/perlvar.html#General-Variables) which holds the version of the current Perl interpreter as a [`version`](https://metacpan.org/pod/version) object (or `undef` if the version is earlier than v5.6).

This allows the version to be compared to a [version string constant](http://perldoc.perl.org/perldata.html#Scalar-value-constructors) like `v5.10` which produces a packed string (containing each version ordinal as a character code, so `v5.10 eq "\x05\x0A"` is *true*).

Because v-strings are *strings* you must compare them with the string comparators `lt`, `le`, `eq`, `ge` and `gt`, so you would write something like

```
use v5.6;

if ( $^V ge v5.10 ) { ... }
```

But I wonder how your code would chnage between different versions of Perl? The majority of the changes are syntactical ones that just offer a nicer way of writing certain constructs. It is usually necessary only to write for the earliest version that you want to support. That used to be v5.8, but v5.10 was a major revision and many people are assuming that as a minimal required version now that it is over seven years old.

Comment: @ikegami: Yes. It's last in the list of *Deprecated and removed variables*

Comment: Re "Because v-strings are strings you must compare them with the string comparators", Not so. In fact, all the examples in the documentation for version objects uses numerical comparison operators. String comparison operators work too, but it's definitely not required to use them. ("Version objects overload the `cmp` and `<=>` operators. Perl automatically generates all of the other comparison operators based on those two so all the normal logical comparisons will work.")

Comment: `$]` wasn't actually deprecated. It was a documentation bug that has since been [fixed](http://perl5.git.perl.org/perl.git/commitdiff/4ad0ecd4c5a81ed8f71804b908656dca23f4867e).